# How do I add different button clicks in one event method?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have the following code in VB.NET, and it works well.

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click, btn1.Click, btn2.Click, btn1.Click
    MsgBox("Hello world")
End Sub
```

It seems not to be working in C#. How do I implement this in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C# it should be like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // You should first subscribe the same handler to each button's click event:
    btnAdd.Click += btnAdd_Click;
    btn1.Click += btnAdd_Click;
    btn2.Click += btnAdd_Click;
}

void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello world");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using `+=` To Assign Event Handlers**

You can use the `+=` operator to indicate that you are going to be [wiring up an event handler delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) for a specific button:

```
// This will wire up the Click event to trigger your btnAdd_Click method
btnAdd.Click += btnAdd_Click;

// Wire up additional elements here
btn1.Click += btnAdd_Click;
btn2.Click += btnAdd_Click;
```

where your `btnAdd_Click` method is defined as such:

```
public void btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello world");
}
```

**Defining Within Your ASPX Page**

Additionally, you can handle this within your ASPX page by using the `OnClick` event exposed by a Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" ... OnClick="btnAdd_Click"></asp:Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to manually attach all of the button's events to your single event handler, like so:

```
btnAdd.Click += new System.EventHandler(btnAdd_Click);
btn1.Click += new System.EventHandler(btnAdd_Click);
btn2.Click += new System.EventHandler(btnAdd_Click);
```